Amend commit and quickly rebase all the dependencies
I a question regarding Git commit amend. Here is the illustration:
Say we have 2 commits, commit hash a1a1a1 with branch A, and commit hash b1b1b1 with B. Currently we are on b
parent--- a1a1a1 (A) --- b1b1b1 (B)
                            ^
                            |
                           HEAD

Then I realized that there are some changes needed, but logically should be part of commit A. So I checkout A
parent--- a1a1a1 (A) --- b1b1b1 (B)
             ^
             |
            HEAD

Made the change and commit with git commit --amend, without changing the commit message. Now the tree looks like
parent--- a1a1a1 --- b1b1b1 (B)
      \
       -- a2a2a2 (A)
             ^
             |
            HEAD

Where a2a2a2 contains the new fix and has exactly the same commit message as a1a1a1. In order to make B to use the right commit, I will need to do the following thing:
git branch -D B # remove old B branch
git switch -c B # create a new B branch
git cherry-pick b1b1b1 # move the old commit b1b1b1 to here

Then the result looks like
parent--- a1a1a1 --- b1b1b1
      \
       -- a2a2a2 (A) --- b2b2b2 (B)
                            ^
                            |
                           HEAD

This process is tedious, especially when you have more branches depending on each other. Is there a quick way to do that?

Follow up
Things get way more nasty when a merge coming into play....
parent--- a1a1a1 (A) --- b1b1b1 (B) --- d1d1d1(D)
      \                               /
       -- c1c1c1 (C) -----------------

In this case when you want to do an git commit --amend on A, it is very hard to manage the correctness of the other branches, especially the merged commit
Background
In industrial situation when we need to collaborate, I cannot wait for A to merge before working on B. So what I have to do is to put A code up for review, at the same time working on B.
It is likely that someone gives a good comment on A and I need to address as part of the commit, which is why I want to use git commit --amend. After address that comment, I need to continue to work on B, or maybe a merged commit of D. It is very annoying keep rebasing stuffs.

If I understand correctly, you can try to use git rebase -i -r.

You could use experimental git replay feature to do it (which is made for such cases). See these answers for more details: git replay, scripted

Trying to avoid changing history too often is probably a good idea. As for speeding up, rebase --onto may be faster than the cherry pick, rebase --update-refs can help with other refs, rebase --rebase-merges can help with merges, but rebasing merge commits comes with its own problem of how to correctly re-create the merge. Fwiw I use --onto frequently, but never --update-refs and never --rebase-merges. More at man git-rebase.


In industrial situation when we need to collaborate, I cannot wait for A to merge before working on B. So what I have to do is to put A code up for review, at the same time working on B.
It is likely that someone gives a good comment on A and I need to address as part of the commit...

To answer that specific situation, here's a better workflow when you are "anticipating a branch".
Put A and B in their own branches. B builds on A. Submit branchA for review. Your repository would look like so.
1 - 2 - 3 [branchA]
         \
          4 - 5 - 6 [branchB]

Make whatever changes you like to branchA. You could add more commits, amend commits, remove commits, and so on. Generally you should be making corrections to pushed branches by adding new commits, not rewriting old ones. Here we've added a commit which addresses a review comment.
1 - 2 - 3 - 7 [branchA]
         \
          4 - 5 - 6 [branchB]

Then rebase your local branchB onto branchA.
$ git switch branchB
$ git rebase branchA

1 - 2 - 3 - 7 [branchA]
             \
              4A - 5A - 6A [branchB]

This will rewrite commits 4, 5, and 6 as if they were on top of 7 all along. This will change their commit IDs, so it's important that branchB is not pushed until branchA is complete. Or if you do push branchB, you must git push --force-with-lease.

In the more general case when you want to amend an earlier commit...
Amending a commit is most useful to amend the most recent commit. As you've discovered, it's less useful for amending previous commits.
Instead, do an interactive rebase. If you want to work on the previous commit, git rebase -i HEAD~2. See gitrevisions for what HEAD~2 means. You'll get an editor like this...
pick a1a1a1 Did something cool
pick b1b1b1 Made it 24% cooler

# Rebase parent..b1b1b1 onto parent

Edit the line to change pick to edit.
edit a1a1a1 Did something cool
pick b1b1b1 Made it 24% cooler

# Rebase parent..b1b1b1 onto parent

Save and quit. Git will guide you through editing and amending that commit and handle rewriting it and b1b1b1 on top of parent for you.

Thanks! Will give it a try and report back. Really appreciate for the detailed anwser!

@Major Great, I hope it works out.
